# Base64 encoded images in Inkscape SVGs

Tags: inkscape, base64

Is there an Export / Save option in Inkscape so that the data of base64 encoded raster images in the SVGs is put on a *single* line instead of being split into multiple lines?

Comment: I don't think this is supported.  What's the use case?

Comment: @leeharvey1 how it shows up in version control (diffs). afaicr earlier versions of Inkscape put the base64 on one line.